# How make Standalone with Subpreambles respect group?

Tags: token-lists, standalone

I am trying to use the subpreambles option with the standalone package. My main file is:

```
\documentclass[subpreambles]{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}

\newtoks{\MyToken}
\MyToken={MainFile}

\begin{document}
Before Input: MyToken = \the\MyToken  \par
\input{MySubfile.tex} \par
After Input: MyToken = \the\MyToken
\end{document}
```

and the MySubfile.tex content is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}

\ifdefined\MyToken% prevent redfintion.
\else%
    \newtoks{\MyToken}%
\fi%

\MyToken={Subfile}

\begin{document}
In sub file: MyToken = \the\MyToken
\end{document}
```

The output from this is:

> Before Input: MyToken = Subfile
>   In sub file: MyToken = Subfile
>   After Input: MyToken = Subfile

but I what I want is this:

> Before Input: MyToken = MainFile
>   In sub file: MyToken = Subfile
>   After Input: MyToken = MainFile

I tried using \begingroup \endgroup around the input and that did not work. I don't want to use different tokens in the standalone and main files, as what is currently the main file, will eventually also be a subfile.  I am not stuck using \newtoks, any method that I can use to achieve this is fine.

I am also ok with last line printing

> Input: MyToken = Subfile

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you not just checking for `\ifdefined\MyToken` instead? The `\TokensDeclared` isn't really required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `subpreamble` option of the `standalone` *package* (you set it on the class for some reason, which works as well because the classes are ignoring unknown options and passing all options to all packages) copies the sub-preambles (i.e. the preambles of the sub-files) to the preamble of the main file. The preambles are written into an auxiliary file and read in again in future runs *in the preamble*, not when the sub-files are read, of course.

Therefore `\MyToken={Subfile}` is executed in the main preamble, not in the `\input`. You will have to move it after the `\begin{document}` in the sub-file to make it work as you want.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but that won't quite work for me as I need access to those token at `\begin{document}`, and would really prefer to NOT have to duplicate the same information before and after `\begin{document}`.  Is there possibly another way I can do achieve this?

Comment: @Peter: You could use the `filehook` package and place them into a file hook for that file: `\AtBeginOfInputFile{MySubfile}{...}`. This would move that code from the main preamble to the `\input` command. However, you need to make sure that the code is executed right away when the subfile is compiled alone. There is the `\ifstandalone` switch, but it might not work if the main file also uses the `standalone` class.

Comment: I don't think that will work for me. It seems that that will  just move the main preamble settings to the subfile. The subfile has its own settings and I need those in the subfile. It guess what I am looking for is something that just ignores the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` in **all** `\input` files. So, perhaps I can use the `filehook` package to do that?

Comment: @Peter: The `standalone` class ignores `\documentclass ` and `\begin{document}` and everything between them. I think the last part is was causes problems for you. The `filehook` package won't help you here, only in combination with `standalone`.

Comment: I was thinking of switching to not use standalone, and use filehook to set `\usepackage`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` to gobble, with the `\AtBeginOfEveryFile` and switch them back to normal via `\AtEndOfEveryFile`. Not exactly sure how to do all that, but am willing to give it a try unless there is something horribly wrong with that logic? The documentation for `filehook` seems to indicate that it will do proper nesting, so that once I return back to the main document, the `\end{document}` should work fine. Any thoughts on this approach?